Why do we sometimes gain the pronomen "man" when we convert between active and passive, and sometimes drop it?

Wandeln Sie die aktiven Sätze ins Passiv um und umgekehrt, wenn möglich

Fische und Frösche werden durch den Wind an Orte getragen, wo man sie nicht erwartet

Gut 90 Prozent des Plastikmülls, der seit 1950 angefallen ist, wurde verbrannt oder landete auf Müllhalden

Beim Export von Müll wird in der Regel nicht kontrolliert, was dann damit geschieht.


Antworten:

Der Wind trägt Fische und Frösche an Orte, wo sie nicht erwartet werden

Man hat gut 90 Prozent des Plastikmülls, der seit 1950 angefallen ist, verbrannt, oder er landete auf Müllhalden

Beim Export von Müll kontrolliert man in der Regel nicht, was dann damit geschieht.



Why in 1. and 2., we gained a pronon 'man' but in 3. , we lost it?
Note:
I have made the following identifications.
First part of 1. is passive, the second is active.
Entire 2. is passive
Entire 3. is passive

When you convert a passive sentence into active, you need a subject for the verb.
One characteristic of passive voice, in German as in English, is that it need not name the actor of the action expressed by the verb.
In sentence 1 the actor is given by the clause "durch den Wind", so you have "der Wind" as the subject for the active sentence.
In sentence 2 and 3, no such clause is present, so you do not have a subject for the active sentence and hence need to use "man" as a replacement.
